# Assigning random colour from RGB into a image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am implement a picture using OpenCV with Python, the requirement is to assign random R,G,B colour to every pixel into the image.

Here is my current code:

```
red, green, blue = (255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255)
rgb = [red, green, blue]
image = img_gen(width, height, rgb_color = random.choice(rgb))

width, height = 640, 480

def img_gen(width, height, rgb_color=(0, 0, 0)):
  ...
    for x in range (0, width):
      for y in range (0, height):
          # what code should be inserted here?
```

I can now implement a picture with assigning only one random choice to fill in the whole image, but I want to know hot to access to every "pixel".

Comment: Where does the img_gen comes from

Comment: Oh, this is the function you want to create. You need to specify how you want to allocate this image. Usually images are 1d arrays with width, padding and height.

Comment: I added my function declaration, for now my problem is I don't know how to assign random colour into every pixel within `width` and `height`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your img_gen function returns, but to get a random entry from rgb you can use

be sure to `import random`
try :

```
img = []
for x in range (0, width):
    for y in range (0, height):
        img.append(rgb[random.randint(0,2)])
return img
```

It really depends on the image format openCV expects in the functions you want to use.

edit :

if you are using numpy you should use

```
img = np.array(width*height)
```

then refer to the content with

```
img[x*width + y] = ....
```

Comment: Thank you. I want to return the entire image with every pixel randomly assigned R or G or B value.

Comment: I got this error after trying your code: `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'`, although I added `import numpy as np` at the beginning.

Comment: My current declare is `img = np.zeros((height, width, 3), np.uint8)` do I need to replace with `np.array(width*height)`, seems I got same error after replacing them

Comment: It really depends on the function you want to call from OpenCV

Answer (score 3):

Using numpy, it's easy to create an image with randomly colored pixels. For use with OpenCV, you often want the data type to be uint8 (integers from 0 to 255):

```
import numpy as np
width, height = 640, 480
img = np.round(np.random.rand(height, width, 3) * 255).astype(np.uint8)
print(img.shape)  # (480, 640, 3)
print(img.dtype)  # uint8
```

Note that numpy uses height before width :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use -

```
img = np.random.rand(width, height, 3);
```

This will create random pixel values.

CAVEAT - RGB values will be between [0,1] and not [0,255].